# Python: 'ModuleNotFoundError' when trying to import module from the same package

Tags: python, python-3.x, traceback, modulenotfounderror

I am using python 3.9 on PyCharm in Windows 10.
The structure of my project is this:

```
/application
   /model
      /games.py
      /lock.py
      /pointClass.py
   /resources
     ...file



/lib
   ...file
```

On Pycharm ty program works but if i try to open it on bash (on Linux or MacOs) it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "games.py", line 16, in <module>
    from application.model.lock import RWLock
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
```

In my **games.py** file i write this to import other file:

```
from application.model.lock import RWLock
from application.model.pointClass import *
```

How can i resolve this problem?
If you wanted to look at my entire project you can go on this github repo: https://github.com/MarioAvolio/BomberFriends

Comment: from which directory you are trying to run the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the file `games.py` and `lock.py` and `pointClass.py` is in the same folder so why not importing it directly like this :

```
from lock import RWLock
from pointClass import *
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because Pycharm sets up its own virtual environment while when running from a terminal you need to set it up your self,I recreated your problem and found the solution ,first you can remove the absolute import and use:

```
from lock import RWlock
```

or you can edit your environment and set up the sys.path at the top of games.py like this:

```
sys.path.append('Path to your project')
```